# Columns With Multiple Unpivot or For

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

I have the below table structure

```
CREATE TABLE test_unpivot
(
   prod_id              NUMBER,
   prod_name_reuse      VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_cat_reuse       VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_name_transfer   VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_cat_transfer    VARCHAR2 (1),
   remarks              VARCHAR2 (10)
);
```

I am using unpivot as

```
    SELECT prod_id, value1, col1
  FROM test_unpivot2 UNPIVOT (value1
                     FOR col1
                     IN (prod_name_reuse, prod_cat_reuse))
 WHERE prod_id = 120
```

and gives the results as

```
+---------+--------+-----------------+
| PROD_ID | VALUE1 |      COL1       |
+---------+--------+-----------------+
|     120 | Y      | PROD_NAME_REUSE |
|     120 | N      | PROD_CAT_REUSE  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+
```

My question is using UNPIVOT, is it possible to achieve the below result?
i.e. prod_name_transfer is another column and should appear as value2.
Does UNPIVOT support multiple FOR..IN statement?

```
+---------+--------+-----------------+--------+---------------------+
| PROD_ID | VALUE1 |      COL1       |VALUE2 |      COL2            |
+---------+--------+-----------------+--------+---------------------+
|     120 | Y      | PROD_NAME_REUSE | Y      | PROD_NAME_TRANSFER  |
|     120 | N      | PROD_CAT_REUSE  | N      | PROD_NAME_TRANSFER  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

[Test table and data](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E06KDHT4AVMZV2BE7C87T6FI0.html)

My actual table has around 54 columns with many records.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE test_unpivot2
(
   prod_id              NUMBER,
   prod_name_reuse      VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_cat_reuse       VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_name_transfer   VARCHAR2 (1),
   prod_cat_transfer    VARCHAR2 (1),
   remarks              VARCHAR2 (10)
);
```

**Table data**

```
INSERT INTO test_unpivot2
     VALUES (120,
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Test1');

INSERT INTO test_unpivot2
     VALUES (121,
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Test2');

INSERT INTO test_unpivot2
     VALUES (122,
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Test3');

INSERT INTO test_unpivot2
     VALUES (123,
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Y',
             'N',
             'Test4');

COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you add the example data that gives your actual/expected outputs in the question (rather than in an offsite link)?

Comment: @MT0 I have included table structure and data in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you even need to use `UNPIVOT`?

```
SELECT id,
       prod_name_reuse      AS value1,
       'PROD_NAME_REUSE'    AS col1,
       prod_name_transfer   AS value2,
       'PROD_NAME_TRANSFER' AS col2
FROM   test_unpivot
WHERE  id = 120
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       prod_cat_reuse      AS value1,
       'PROD_CAT_REUSE'    AS col1,
       prod_cat_transfer   AS value2,
       'PROD_CAT_TRANSFER' AS col2
FROM   test_unpivot
WHERE  id = 120;
```

**Update**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT u.*,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( type, '_(.+?)_', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS namecat,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( type, '[^_]+$' ) AS reusetransfer
  FROM   testunpivot
  UNPIVOT (
    value
    FOR type IN (
      prod_name_reuse,
      prod_cat_reuse,
      prod_name_transfer,
      prod_cat_transfer
    )
  ) u
)
PIVOT (
  MAX( value ) AS value,
  MAX( type  ) AS col
  FOR reusetransfer IN ( 'REUSE', 'TRANSFER' )
);
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, in my actual table, I have 54 columns and I prefer to use UNPIVOT.

Comment: I forgot to mention, certainly UNION ALL is not an option for me.

Comment: @user75ponic Updated